# Java 8 parallelstream worker issue

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, forkjoinpool

I am running a weekly job using java 8 springboot. I use forkjoin custom pool. With 8 threads, I see that the job takes 3 hours to complete. When I check the logs I see that the performance/throughput or is consistent till about 80% and I see almost 5 to 6 threads are running fine. But after the job completes around 80% I see only one thread running and the performance/throughput is decreased drastically.

Going with initial analysis I feel some how the threads are lost after 80%. Not sure thought.

Question:
1) Any hints on what is going wrong?
2) What is best way to debug this issue and fix it, so the all threads run correctly till job completes.

I think the job should be complete within lesser time than it is now, and I feel threads might be the issue.

Comment: Your work is not divisible enough. You don't `fork()` enough. Or you are generally using the pool wrong (for example calling `.fork().join()`). In general, your threads are work starved - recreate the issue and take thread dumps, or use flight recorder, to determine where the issue lies. Without any code, this question cannot be answered more specifically so I'm going to vote to close as "too broad".

Comment: It is always better to add some sample code which will help SO members to understand your issue